# How can i add a loop to json obj

Tags: python

i tried to add while and for loop to this bot and I couldn't manage to get that right
does it matter where i put the for loop? would love to get some help thank you!

```
import requests
import json

API_TOKEN = ""

# api-endpoint

URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + API_TOKEN + "/sendphoto"
keyboard= json.dumps({ "inline_keyboard": [ [ {"text": "ticket", "url": "https://t.me/t"}, {"text": "Bye", "callback_data": "x"}, {"text": "I love you", "callback_data": "x"} ] ] })

multipart_form_data = {
    'photo': ('pic.png', open('pic.png', 'rb')),
    'action': (None, 'send'),
    'chat_id': (None, ''),
    'caption': (None, 'This is a *description* of the _image_'),
    'parse_mode': (None, 'Markdown'),
    'reply_markup': (None, keyboard )
}

response = requests.post(URL, files=multipart_form_data)
data = response.json()
print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

I tried this way

```
while True:
    response = requests.post(URL, files=multipart_form_data)
```

Didn't work tried for loop

```
for x in response:
    response = requests.post(URL, files=multipart_form_data)
```

didn't work either what am im missing

Comment: Loops consist of a body which is repeated and some sort of condition which defines when the loop will end. Please update your question with a description of these two parts. (Also, since you seem to be using a 'post' you may want to consider a delay so that you are not seen as sending spam)

Answer (score 0):

i manage to find a solution with def function

```
import requests
```

import json

API_TOKEN = ""

## api-endpoint

```
def send():
    try:
        URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + API_TOKEN + "/sendphoto"

        keyboard = json.dumps({"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "Contact", "url": "https://t.me/giliargov"}, ]]})

        multipart_form_data = {
            'photo': ('pic.png', open('pic.png', 'rb')),
            'action': (None, 'send'),
            'chat_id': (None, '-1001672825916'),
            'caption': (None, 'This is a *description* of the _image_'),
            'parse_mode': (None, 'Markdown'),
            'reply_markup': (None, keyboard)



    }
        response = requests.post(URL, files=multipart_form_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

while True:
    send()
```

added function to the whole code and while loop the function